# OOP real_escape_string

Tags: php, oop, mysqli

I have problem with mysqli_real_escape_string , I'm trying all but it still giving me an error:

> "Fatal error: Call to undefined method Database::real_escape_string()"

**My code:
*First file*:**

```
$Database = new Database($host,$user,$pass,$db);
$Form = new Form($Database);
echo $Form->GET('key');
```

***Second file:***

```
class Form{
    public $mysqli;

    function __construct($con){
        $this->mysqli = $con;
    }

    function GET($string) {
        return $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($string);
    }
}
```

***Database:***

```
class Database {
    public $connection;

    public function __construct($host,$user,$pass,$db) {
        $this->Connect($host,$user,$pass,$db);
    }

    function Connect($host,$user,$pass,$db) {
        $this->connection = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db);
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

As you can see in construct i've saved the mysqli connection, but i really dont know why it doesnt know what is real_escape

Comment: `escape_string()` != `real_escape_string()`

Comment: Your error message doesn't match your code. Also we have no idea what `Database` is meaning nobody can answer his.

Comment: All looks pretty undirected. Good chance you are wrapping  `->mysqli` twice in the `Database` class and in `Form`.

Comment: Now that you have posted your `Database` class and seeing the error message it should be pretty clear. There is no method called `real_escape_string` in the class `Database`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that

```
function __construct($con){
    $this->mysqli = $con;
}
```

accepts not object of class `mysqli`, but object of class `Database`, which has property `connection` which is object of class `mysqli`.
So, proper call would be:

```
function GET($string) {
    return $this->mysqli->connection->real_escape_string($string);
}
```

Though I'm not sure if `$this->mysqli->connection->` will be parsed correctly.

Comment: wow, it works! :) thanks